Bitbucket pipeline failing while running automation with playwright python
This is my yml file
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.47.0-noble

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install Dependencies
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install --upgrade pip
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - pip install pytest allure-pytest  # Explicitly install pytest and allure-pytest
          - python -m playwright install --with-deps

    - step:
        name: Run Playwright Tests
        script:
          - python -m pytest tests/ --alluredir=allure-results

    - step:
        name: Generate Allure Report
        script:
          - allure serve allure-results

    - step:
        name: Archive Allure Results
        artifacts:
          - allure-results/**
        script:
          - echo "Allure results archived."

Error- Message:
+ python -m pytest tests/ --alluredir=allure-results
/usr/bin/python: No module named pytest

I tried pytest tests/ also but same error.
How can I fix the error?

Could you please provide your requirements.txt file
